# More simple Lisp functions not working

Tags: lisp

I am trying to make a function that counts the number of lists within a list.

```
 (defun test (a)
           (if (equal a nil) (return-from test 0))
           (if (not (listp a)) (print "case a") (return-from test (+ 0 (test (cdr a))))
             (print "case b")(return-from test (+ 1 (test (cdr a)))))
           )
```

I don't know how the debugger works so I tried some newbie debugging with print statements. The code above does not even execute. I have no idea why. The original code, which works but gives the wrong answer is as follows:

```
 (defun test (a)
           (if (equal a nil) (return-from test 0))
           (if (not (listp a)) (return-from test (+ 0 (test (cdr a))))
             (return-from test (+ 1 (test (cdr a)))))
           )
```

This is returning the number of elements period, whether lists or not. I don't see where I am going wrong. Another problem too, it crashes when I call (test 1) or test on any atom. Of course, you cannot take cdr of an atom but what error checking can I do? What changes can I make to make this ridiculous function work?

Comment: OK, I regret having shown you the `return-from` example ;-) Again, `cond` would saved you here.

Comment: I was not sure about the cond... Meaning in the way it works. Does it check every statement after it finds the first one true or does it only execute the first true statement? That is the only reason I didn't use it. Thanks again for the patience and help!

Comment: @user3270407 If you use Common Lisp, there is info about cond here: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm
In most lisps cond behave the same.

Comment: Only the first one that's true. See http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first block doesn't work because function "if" deals at most with 3 forms in it (condition then-branch else-branch). If you want a few actions in one branch, you should wrap them with progn:

```
(if (not (listp a))
  (progn
    (print "case a")
    (return-from test (+ 0 (test (cdr a)))))
  (progn
    (print "case b")
    (return-from test (+ 1 (test (cdr a))))))
```

Problem with second one is check (listp a). You should check whether first element is list rather than whole list is list (listp (car a)).

I don't know, what dialect of lisp you are using. In most of them form "cond" is available, and special form "return-from" doesn't required. So, you can rewrite you function as follows:

```
(defun test (a)
  (cond
    ((not (listp a)) nil) ; "atom" case
    ((not a) 0) ; empty list case
    ((listp (car a)) ; first element is list
     (print "case list")
     (+ 1 (test (cdr a))))
    (T ; fist element is not list
     (print "case not list")
     (test (cdr a))))) ; avoid adding zero because it has no effect
```

Comment: Why not return 0 if `a` is not a list? The function is supposed to yield a number.

Comment: Yes, progn executes all forms and returns result of last one.

Comment: Thank you all. I am sorry to keep asking the Lisp questions!

Comment: @YuriyKovalev Not sure I get you. `(test 1)` should return 0, not `nil`.

Comment: Do you guys have any recommendations on good online Lisp documentation?

Comment: @uselpa It depends on requirements. I believe that if "a" is not a list, it means exception occurred. In this case it will be better to return nil. "Just zero" will hide exceptions from the user of function.

Comment: @YuriyKovalev Well, my point of view is that the number of lists in an atom is 0. And `nil` is not an exception, but doing it like that entails that every calling function has to specifically test for `nil`.

Comment: @uselpa Again, it depends on requirements. Your variant is also acceptable, if calling function doesn't care about passing list as parameter.

Comment: @user3270407: If you are using Common Lisp, all of the chapters of Practical Common Lisp are available online: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/. Also look at the Common Lisp Hyperspec for specific function by function documentation.